# Directory structure of Octopress

Tags: directory, blogs, octopress

I want to understand the entire directory structure of Octopress. Each and every folder and how they fit in together. Could not find any docs online.

ex: What is the difference between public and _deploy folder?

Help and Pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to explain every folder to you?

Comment: I am just asking the purpose of every folder. It is documented nowhere so a Stack Overflow question will help a lot of people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_deploy/`:

> (After run `rake generate` `rake deploy`)This will generate your blog, copy the generated files into _deploy/, add them to git, commit and push them up to the master branch. In a few seconds you should get an email from Github telling you that your commit has been received and will be published on your site. via [Deploying to Github Pages](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/)

`public`:
compiled site directory,your `public` directory will be synced to your
remote page.

**Difference：**`public/` is a rack convention and it gets wiped with each generate. `_deploy/` is contains a git repo for gh-pages deployment. via [@Brandon Mathis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341748/brandon-mathis)

```
root:               # Mapping for relative urls (default: /)
    source/         # Directory for site source files
      _includes/    # Main layout partials
        custom/     # <- Customize head, header, navigation, footer, and sidebar here
        asides/     # Theme sidebar partials
        post/       # post metadata, sharing & comment partials
      _layouts/     # layouts for pages, posts & category archives

permalink:          # Permalink structure for blog posts
destination:        # Directory for generated site files
plugins:            # Directory for Jekyll plugins
code_dir:           # Directory for code snippets (for include_code plugin)
category_dir:       # Directory for generated blog category pages
```

Here’s a list of files for [configuring Octopress](http://octopress.org/docs/configuring/).

```
_config.yml       # Main config (Jekyll's settings)
Rakefile          # Configs for deployment
config.rb         # Compass config
config.ru         # Rack config
```

See the full documentation at [Octopress Documentation](http://octopress.org/docs/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still dont understand the purpose of public. For serving remote pages we have _deploy right? Why public? Sorry if its too much of a newbie question.

Comment: _deploy directory isn't keep in version control. [More info](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/412)

Comment: public/ is a rack convention and it gets wiped with each generate. _deploy/ is contains a git repo for gh-pages deployment. via [@Brandon Mathis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/341748/brandon-mathis) [More info](https://twitter.com/imathis/status/246096880591851520)

Comment: `_deploy/` is only created if you're deploying to GitHub pages. It contains a `.git` directory which would be wiped out by Jekyll each time it is generated if it were used as the "compiled site" directory. For those who are deploying to Heroku, some rack server of their own, public is a standard name for "files to be hosted publicly" and it is automatically served up by Rack.